# How to display combined stats for multiple domains in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I run multiple domains that are not related to each other and are all tracked by Google Analytics on separate web properties (different tracking code, same Google Account).

I am wondering if there is a way by which I could view all of the stats combined (e.g. total pageviews, visitors, or even total real-time users browsing all of my sites right now). I don't mind connecting my Google Analytics account with 3rd party apps which would analyse the data.

With the real-time viewer stats I could then perhaps estimate the capacity of my web server. Otherwise, simply knowing how many people visited your site this month, without having to manually add all stats together, is something that is nice to know and allows you to see your overall performance of your sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/Fabj1bWqHo4) post in the Google Analytics forum, the new [Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en&ref_topic=2790009) (in Beta) provides the ability to use the same tracking code across all your sites.

This will require creating a new profile, which should then display the option to use "Universal Analytics" instead of "Classic Analytics". For more on how to setup Universal Analytics, see [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2817075?hl=en&ref_topic=2790009).

For tracking multiple domains with Classic Analytics, see this:  [Google Analytics - Set up cross-domain tracking for multiple domains.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en&ref_topic=2772342)

There are also numerous web analytics applications that can be added to analyze your web server's logs for all your sites. You might find it easier to use one of these apart from Google Analytics to monitor your web server's usage. For a list of these, see: [List of web analytics software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software)

Lastly, the best way to estimate the capacity of your web server is to monitor your server's system resources and performance during peak times using a utility like `top` in Linux, or Task Manager in Windows. Here's a link to help with that in a Linux server/VPS: 
[Linux resource monitoring tools and techniques](http://wiki.vpslink.com/Monitor_Linux_System_Resources)