# Adding more than one Google Analytics tracking code to a site - is this ok?

Tags: analytics

We have several sites that would like to aggregate all the analytics details, along with the individual site details.

AFAIK, there isn't a way to do this from the GA interface.  Is it alright to add another GA code to each site to allow us to track all details from one GA property?

Answer (score 1):

[From Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en) on multiple tracking codes:

> Installing multiple instances of the Google Analytics Tracking code on a single web page is not a supported implementation. We suggest you remove all but one instance, and make sure you have the code from the correct view installed on every page you would like to track.

You may be interested in the answer to the question [How to display combined stats for multiple domains in Google Analytics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50565/how-to-display-combined-stats-for-multiple-domains-in-google-analytics) by [dan](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/28389/dan)

> According to [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/Fabj1bWqHo4) post in the Google Analytics forum, the new [Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en&ref_topic=2790009) (in Beta) provides the ability to use the same tracking code across all your sites.
>
> This will require creating a new profile, which should then display the option to use "Universal Analytics" instead of "Classic Analytics". For more on how to setup Universal Analytics, see [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2817075?hl=en&ref_topic=2790009).
>
> For tracking multiple domains with Classic Analytics, see this:  [Google Analytics - Set up cross-domain tracking for multiple domains.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en&ref_topic=2772342)
>
> There are also numerous web analytics applications that can be added to analyze your web server's logs for all your sites. You might find it easier to use one of these apart from Google Analytics to monitor your web server's usage. For a list of these, see: [List of web analytics software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software)

Answer (score 0):

I think Google already has a solution for your requirement, check [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite) for more details.

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide more details.  Answering with just a link isn't encouraged here.  The content at the link may go away or change.  In addition, its much more helpful if you can provide enough information that users don't need to click on the link, but can get enough info to solve their problem directly from your post.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I understand your point of view, but some case like this answering in details is not possible.So next time own words in will improve my answer formats. thanks..

Answer (score -1):

Look at: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite for more information on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please don't share the same link as Jobin Jose's one. Provide your own answer.

Comment: This is the same link provided by Jobin Jose.  Providing answers with just a link is not particularly helpful, especially when somebody else has already posted the link.  It is much better to give a summary of the solution in addition to the link.  Resources in links change or go away.  In addition, answers are more useful when they provide sufficient info in the answer without a click on the link.